# How to convert xmllist to xml in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

How do I convert something like

```
<a/>
<b/>
```

to a structured xml like below in jquery

```
<parent>
 <a/>
 <b/>
</parent>
```

I am getting the xml as a file from server (as xmlDoc).

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap it? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes thats what I am trying to do... I tried $(xml).wrap('<parent />') but it doesnt seem to be working for non html tags names! Likewise I tried combination of before() and append() too...